# Keep scroll position in ADF page

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a page with few forms in it and a submit button to save the records. If there is any errors then I m displaying the error messages programmatically in faces message .

But after clicking on the ok button on the af message, the page scrolls to the top and I have to scroll down again to click the button.

Is there any way to save the scroll position in ADF . I tried to call Java script

Window.scrollto () method

But for other methods it's working fine but not after clicking on the af message ok button.

Please let me know any way to scroll down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is not really JS issue, since with JSF (I suppose) Your page is simply being submitted, redirect occurs (on the same page) and thats why page is not scrolled. You could implement some ugly hack like keeping scroll position inside **sessionStorage** but first ask Yourself is that really what You need https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: And if tries to think why the page scroll to the top? Are There buttons  invoking an actonListener with partialSubmit = true? In this case, the page should not scroll top but if you invokes an action method yes..

Answer (score 1):

markosca already gave the correct hints as a comment.
I'll clarify a bit on this for the sake of a complete answer:

- If your buttons trigger an action, always a complete new site will be loaded.
  Even if the "new" site is equal to the old one, it will seem as if the site has scrolled up.
- If your buttons have an actionListener registered, this scrolling will also happen. Even if you put an addPartialTarget(...) inside that registered Java-method.

So, how to solve this? It's easy, just **use an actionListener and the attribute partialSubmit="true"** on the button or link.

Only than a partial submit will be executed instead of a full page reload.

And don't forget to either use addPartialTarget(...) in Java or the attribute partialTriggers="..." on the components which should update because of that partial submit.